# SharePoint 2010 People Picker without connection to Active Directory

Tags: dmz

I have a SharePoint in the DMZ with no connections to the certain Active Directory. All ports are blocked. When I search for users in that domain, I can't find them obviously.

Is it possible to somehow point the People Picker to a database (or a service) which I could install and from time to time import all the users from that not reachable Domain?

The other solutions (I do not know how viable) would be to import all the user from that Domain to a Sharepoint group with no specific access. Is that possible?

Comment: You can create your own custom field with people picker functionality, using C#. Or You can deploy AD to the same DMZ.

Comment: Deploying is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: ok, You can create custom field. Or You can add choice field and add user names as options.